# What is this Java code equivalent in C# ? (setRequestEntity)

Tags: java, c#

There is a HTTP server developed in Java which utilizes `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, etc.. In this server there is a method to be called by "POST" and receive one parameter, a huge string.

Normally this method is called by a `Java` application and it works fine, the code used to call is the following:

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(this.serverUrl);
post.setRequestEntity(new CrossTalkRequestEntity(msg));
HttpClient cli = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
int code = cli.executeMethod(post);
```

The parameter to send is the `msg` variable, look that there isn't a named parameter to do the POST.

The problem is: When I try to do a POST to this server, I can't send my `string` parameter without a named parameter, the following code is how the server get the value of the parameter:

```
requestMessage = JaxbHelper.createContextAndUnmarshal(CrossTalkMessage.class, request.getInputStream());
```

Look that the server doesn't get the parameter by a name, it just call `request.getInputStream()` and get the value.

I have tried a lot of ways to do this, now I'm trying to call using the method below, but it is not working, because I am passing a named parameter `value` and not setting a request entity like Java calls (`setRequestEntity`).

```
      public static string Post(string address, string data)
        {
            string responseFromServer = string.Empty;
            WebResponse response = null;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("value=" + data);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            response.Close();
}
```

How could I call this HTTP server in `c#` and pass the parameter like `Java` do?

**EDIT**
There is the code of class `CrossTalkRequestEntity`:

```
class CrossTalkRequestEntity implements RequestEntity {

                private final byte[] data;

                CrossTalkRequestEntity(CrossTalkMessage msg) {
                               ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                               try {
                                               JaxbHelper.createContextAndMarshal(CrossTalkMessage.class, msg, out);
                               } finally {
                                               try {
                                                               out.flush();
                                                               out.close();
                                               } catch (IOException e) {
                                               }
                               }
                               this.data = out.toByteArray();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isRepeatable() {
                               return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void writeRequest(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                               out.write(data);
                }

                @Override
                public long getContentLength() {
                               return data.length;
                }

                @Override
                public String getContentType() {
                               return "text/xml";
                }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to do `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);` instead of `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("value=" + data);`?

Comment: Yes, I have. When I try this, the value of `data` continue be sending like a parameter, but with another name (because in the content of `data` variable there is a `foo=bar` string)

Comment: Also, in Java example you are embedding an entire object, "new CrossTalkRequestEntity(msg)"... I am guessing your receiver wants to deserialize this? Thus, you need to construct a similiar obj in C# and append its stream to your msg.

Comment: then remove it. I suspect the problem is in the way you serialize the content to get it as an string. Can you add the code you use to serialize the class as JSON?

Comment: @RichardTyregrim This is not the point. The point is: When the server do `request.getInputStream()` he don't get my parameter.  `CrossTalkRequestEntity` is just a class which inherit from  `RequestEntity` Java class and return a `byte[]`.

Comment: Can you intercept a send from Java client and see what it looks like? Compare that to a sent msg from C# client? If so, look at the payload and compare.

Comment: @Gusman I cant remove it, the `data` content is an `XML` and obviously in one `XML` will have a lot of  `foo=bar` in attributes.

Comment: Still, appending the entire object, will probably append additional stuff apart from the string, because it hasa overhead no matter how simple the object is. So i would try the Java code, and send just a string, then the same in C# and compare. If they are the same, then investigate what is added when doing the Java call the way it is now.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind no,that's not right, on java, if you set setRequestEntity it will serialize the content as JSON, so it will not have any "foo=bar", it will contain a JSON object, so the problem lies there, you need to serialize the content as JSON, add the code for serialization and add the definition of your java class CrossTalkRequestEntity so we can see the structure it must have.

Comment: @RichardTyregrim Yes I have already done it. When I call by `C#` the value of my parameter is on a `parameters` property of the `HttpServletRequest` object. But when I call by `Java` I didn't find the value of the parameter

Comment: @Gusman Ok, I will add the content of the `CrossTalkRequestEntity` class

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind and the C# serialization code, very important.

Comment: @Gusman the Serialization code is an external library, is not my code.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind yes, you should be using Json. net, what I mean is show us how you call the serialization.

Comment: @Gusman I edited my question with the requested class

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind Okokok, wait, watching the CrossTalkRequestEntity I see you'r java is sending the content as text/xml, so no json at all, so, it's simple, you should have a class X with the model to create the xml, just serialize it using an XmlSerializer and use that string as the input for your Post function, that's all

Comment: Also, your content type is wrong, it must be "text/xml", not "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" at all

Comment: @Gusman The `data` variable already have the `XML` serialized. I will try change the content type.

Comment: @Gusman  WOOWWW the problem was the content type. I set to `text/xml` and all worked  fine! Thank you ^^ Create an answer to me upvote please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a bit on your code the problem is the content type of your request, your original Java code sent the content as "text/xml" while your C# code was sending it as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Change the ContentType to "text/xml" and it will work.